# How to structure this interface in xcode?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I've am learning Objective C by myself and i was trying to do something like this, but i was wondering what would be the best and the most correct way of doing it.
I am using storyboard but it won't matter, since this is for my learning, it can be done with separated xibs.
Just explaining, a bunch of buttons on top (no need to scroll to the sides), that when you touch them, it loads a specific view as if it was a ballon. Not like the tab bars.

Any idea?

Just a PS here, i am not asking for the code ready, just ideas of how to implement it.

Thanks

Here follows the image:

[image: tryout]

Comment: `UIButton` and `UIView` (all in a `UIViewController`) should cover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that, using a custom [Container Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

1. The parent viewController should have all views from the screenShoot
2. The childView Controller should have the view inside the ballon

You can create a list of child viewControllers, and every time one of the circle is click you can change the controller using:

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];                 
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];         
}

- (void) hideContentController: (UIViewController*) content
{
   [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil]; 
   [content.view removeFromSuperview];            
   [content removeFromParentViewController];      
}
```

---

Create a view with the up arrow, and change the center property of it, based on the position of the button that revived the click.

```
-(void)didTouchButton:(UIButton*)target{
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^ {
           CGRect frame = _upArrow.frame;
           frame.origin.x = target.origin.x;
           _upArrow.frame = frame;
       } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
          // here you can added your view controller
       }
 }
```

Comment: Awesome man, seems like this is the way to go, i will be trying and thank you. Obrigado ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this in a number of ways, here are a few suggestions:

1. Use `UIViewController` [containment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) where the button bar is a subview of the `ContainerViewController` and each button displays a `ContentViewController` (the white view with corresponding arrow).
2. Simply have each button in the button bar display a `UIView` subclass (the white area with arrow).
3. Have each button in the button bar trigger the display of a UIPopoverController (white area, with the advantage that the arrow will be be included and positioned for free).
4. If you do need to side scroll the buttons in the button bar you could use a `UICollectionView`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can't use `UIPopoverController` on the iPhone.

Comment: Ahh didnt realize this was iPhone only, err, looks like it doesnt specify device so thanks for noting.

Comment: It's not iPhone-only, it's iPad-only.

Comment: Sorry i didn't specify, but i intend to do iphone AND ipad, so i will have to figure it out for iphone haha. But it's good to have an option to ipad already, thanks mate.

Comment: I meant I didn't realize the question was intended for iPhone only, wasn't talking about popovers.